# How to read KMLfile from local server for Openlayers "EarthQuakes in KML"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, openlayers, kml

I use the following EarthQuake map on my local server:
https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/kml-earthquakes.html

I have a standalone "map.html" for the map in my application in my "Views" folder.
Impementing this works ok, the map loads, and using the examples data:

```
url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag5.kml'
```

The data shows up in the map, all good so far

By going to this'data-url', a file is downloaded. So i download and edit this file with my own KML-datapoints. And then i place this file in the same folder as my "map.html" (The views folder).

I have tried to reference it manually by path, but got some CORS issues, then i sought out some xmlhttprequest, but not sure that is the right path since it's supposed to be a file (?) .....
So it all boils down to:

How do i reference my kml-file from within the script tags in the HTML-eartquake-file to this file in the same folder?

**Update feb 2020:**

I think now the CORS issue is removed. However, when i try to implement this it does not work:

1. If i use the Openlayer example link in the VectorSource - URL; https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag5.kml, my app downloads a file like this: "filename.kml"
2. If i use my own file on my server, i get a file like this "filename"

   - That is without the .kml extension.
   - The url looks like this in this case:    https://myapp.net/mydata.kml

In express/nodejs i send the file like this:

```
router.get("/mydata", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path + "mydata.kml");
});
```

Here is a example from the Chrome download bar:
[image]

How can i send my file WITH extension? And will that solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try opening the kml file on your server via the browser.  You may need to set the MIME type to text/xml

Comment: How?
You know this will work, or are you merely suggesting?

Comment: If you are using IIS you won't be able to access files unless the extension has a MIME type - some such as  .json are predefined but .geojson and .kml are not.

Comment: I'am using IIS, however, i guess i cant replace  the above url with:
url: '<input type="MIME" name="myFile">' as this is html, and i need JS ?
So, in other words: I dont know how to reference the file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IIS you need to go to the management panel and add `.kml` to the MIME types.  If you are planning a lot a mapping applications adding `.geojson` (application/json) and `.gml` and `.gpx` (text/xml) might also be useful.

[image]

You will also need to enable cross origin access for your data folder

[image]

Comment: Ok! First now i get some sense of this :) Thanks. 
So since this is running in Azure, tried to add it to the web.config file (ref: https://www.adamrussell.com/allow-a-new-mime-type-download-on-wordpress-azure/). And also this way: <mimeMap fileExtension =".kml" mimeType="text/xml"></mimeMap>. Still dev-tools console reports: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myserver/mykmldata.kml' from origin 'http://localhost:1462' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: If you are running from elsewhere you will also need to enable cross origin access for the data.

Comment: Yes, I'm reading the IIS CORS information over at Microsoft. I will read some more and then enable CORS in the web.config file of my server.

Comment: I was thinking this is a IIS issue only. I dont know so much about this, but do i need to install this NPM package on my server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors ?

Comment: My app uses express.js, and is hosted in Azure as a Web-app. Does it use IIS or not? And how do i find out, if any doubt?